# How to query a one to many/many to many relationship in Flask SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

These are two database models that are important in my problem.

**I have established a one to many relationship (a Conversation can have multiple Messages)**  
There is also a many to many relationship established between User and Conversation.

**After obtaining two User objects, say *user1* and *user2*, I need to find the conversation that contains both users, if it exists. After getting a conversation object, say *current_convo*, I also need to query all the messages in that conversation. How could these two queries be done?**

```
class Conversation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'conversation'

    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    users = db.relationship("User", secondary=relationship_table)
    messages = db.relationship("Message", backref="conversation", lazy="dynamic")


class Message(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'message'

    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    message = db.Column('message', db.String)
    timestamp = db.Column('timestamp', db.String)
    sender = db.Column('sender', db.String)
    conversation_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('conversation.id'))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column('username', db.String(100), unique=True, index=True)
    password = db.Column('password', db.String(100))
    email = db.Column('email', db.String(100), unique=True, index=True)
    authenticated = db.Column('authenticated', db.Boolean, default=False)
```

Comment: Can we assume there is only 1 conversation between the two users? Are the instances where multiple conversations between the same two users take place?

Comment: @dirn there already is a one-to-many relationship between Conversation and Message. I just don't know how to write the query it.

Comment: Do you only want conversations between exactly user1 and user2 or do you want conversations that include them and any other participants?

Comment: Sorry. I looked for the relationship on `Message` but not `Conversation`. There is no query to write. `current_convo.messages` is a query set containing the messages.

Comment: @flyingmeatball the Conversations have unique composition in the sense that two Conversation cannot have the exact same members. However, something like conversation1 = {john, bob}, conversation2 = {john, bob, richard} is allowed.

Comment: @dirn I feel quite dumb now. I did not know that I could access it like that. Thanks. Any ideas for the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I know to do this is to use SQLAlchemy's [contains](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.contains).

```
Conversation.query.filter(
    Conversation.users.contains(user1),
    Conversation.users.contains(user2)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a pure SQL query, but here's how I would accomplish what you're asking using Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import urllib

#setup vars and connection
server = 'myServer'
db = 'myDb'

user1 = 'someId1'
user2 = 'someId2'

#You'll have to maybe change this a little if you aren't using a trusted connection on SQL Server
connStr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';Trusted_Connection=yes'
conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % (urllib.quote_plus(connStr)))

#select all conversations that have one of the users
query = """select * from Conversation where users is in ('{0}','{1}')""".format(user1,user2)
conv_df = pd.read_sql(query,conn)

#unstack the users, so we can see which users are part of the same conversation
conv_users = conv_df.set_index(['id','users']).unstack().reset_index()

#filter conversations to those that have both users
conv_together = conv_users[(conv_users[user1].notnull()) & (conv_users[user2].notnull())]

conv_list = conv_together['id'].tolist()
conv_str = "(" + ', '.join("'{0}'".format(w) for w in conv_list) +")"

#select all messages where the conv id matches your criteria (has both users)
query = """select * from Message where conversation_id is in {0}""".format(conv_str)

message_df = pd.read_sql(query,conn)
```

Its hard to show intermediate steps with no test data, so I can't run and QC this code, but hopefully it gives you the right idea.